# Bullet list syntax for Adobe InDesign script

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript

I'm looking for the syntax that defines bullet points so that I can create a bullet list in a script for use as a guide template for other users. At a guess my best bet so far is that it's under 'character styles' but other than that I'm really not sure what to try.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bullet

Property Listing:

Font of the bullet character. Can return: Font, String or AutoEnum enumerator  — 
 `bulletsFont`

Font style of the bullet character. Can return: String, NothingEnum enumerator or AutoEnum enumerator — `bulletsFontStyle`

The type of bullet character — `characterType`

---

Method Listing:

Resolves the object specifier, creating an array of object references — `Bullet getElements ()`

Generates a string which, if executed, will return the Bullet — `String toSource ()`

---

Object of:

`TextDefault.bulletChar`

`Text.bulletChar`

`Character.bulletChar`

`Word.bulletChar`

`Line.bulletChar`

`TextColumn.bulletChar`

`Paragraph.bulletChar`

`TextStyleRange.bulletChar`

`InsertionPoint.bulletChar`

`Story.bulletChar`

`ParagraphStyle.bulletChar`

`XmlStory.bulletChar`

`FindTextPreference.bulletChar`

`FindGrepPreference.bulletChar`

`FindTransliteratePreference.bulletChar`

`ChangeTextPreference.bulletChar`

`ChangeGrepPreference.bulletChar`

`ChangeTransliteratePreference.bulletChar`

`Event.parent`

`EventListener.parent`

`MutationEvent.parent`

---

### BulletCharacterType

Values:

For a glyph with font — `BulletCharacterType.GLYPH_WITH_FONT — Value = 1111713638`

Unicode only — `BulletCharacterType.UNICODE_ONLY — Value = 1111717231`

Unicode with font — `BulletCharacterType.UNICODE_WITH_FONT — Value = 1111717222`

---

Object of:

`Bullet.characterType`

---

### BulletListExportOption

Values:

To convert to text — `BulletListExportOption.AS_TEXT — Value = 1700946804`

Map to html unordered list — `BulletListExportOption.UNORDERED_LIST — Value = 1700949333`

To convert to text — `BulletListExportOption.AS_TEXT — Value = 1700946804`

---

Object of:

`EPubExportPreference.bulletExportOption`

`HTMLExportPreference.bulletExportOption`